# My form doesn't submit information in input text

Tags: php, jquery, forms

I'm doing a table where the user can introduce the number of the products he want to buy and submit them pressing the submission button. I build the content of the table using a sql query (SELECT) setting the name of the input(text) like in the code below. My problem is that, probably, the form doesn't submit nothing because, if a check the variable $_REQUEST with isset(), it return FALSE. Someone can help me? Thanks!

```
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","uPower","","info"); 
    if (mysqli_connect_errno()) 
      printf("<p>Error!!: %s<p>\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    else{
        $query = "SELECT * FROM product"; 
        $result = mysqli_query ($con, $query);  
echo "<form name=\"buy\" action=\"confirm.php\" method=\"POST\" onSubmit=\"return checkInputQty(qty.value) \">";
        echo"<table>";
        echo"<tr><th>Product name</th><th>Price</th><th>Available</th><th>Qty</th></tr>";
         while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
            $pid = $row["pid"];
            $name = $row["name"];
            $qty = $row["qty"];
            $price = ($row['price'])/100;
            echo"<tr><th>$name</th><th>".number_format($price,2,',', '')." &#8364</th><th>$qty</th><th><input type=\"text\" id=".$pid." name=".$name."></th></tr>";
        }
        echo"</table>";
echo "<p><input type=\"submit\" value=\"BUY\" class=\"button\" ><input type=\"button\" onclick=\"clearText()\" value=\"DELETE\" class=\"button\"></p>"; 
echo "</form>";
        mysqli_free_result($result);
        mysqli_close($con);
```

there is the part of confirm.php. It is a function in head that i called from the body of the page. It does a summary of what the user selected to buy. The control with if(isset($_REQUEST)) is false, so the page is blank....

```
<?php 

function checkInputQty(){
    $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","uPower","","info"); 
    if (mysqli_connect_errno()) 
        echo "error DB";
    else{
        $query = "SELECT * FROM product"; 
        $result = mysqli_query ($con, $query);
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){ 
            $nome = $row["name"];
            if(isset($_REQUEST["$name"])){  
                $qty = trim($_REQUEST['$row["name"]']);
                if($qty>0 && $qty<=$row["qty"]){
                    $new_qty = $row["qty"]-$qty;
                    $query2 = "UPDATE product SET qty = '$new_qty' WHERE qty = '".$row["qty"]."' ";
                    $result2 = mysqli_query ($con, $query2);
                    if($result){
                        echo "<table>";
                        echo "<tr><th>Name</th><th></th><th>Price</th></tr>";
                        do_content($row["name"],$qty,$row["price"]/100);
                        echo "</table>";
                    }   
                    else
                        echo "Error!";
                }

            }e

        }
        mysqli_free_result($result);
    }
mysqli_close($con); 
}
```

?>

```
<?php
 function do_content($name,$to_buy,$price){
    echo "<tr><th>$name</th><th>$to_buy</th><th>$price</th></tr>";
 }
?>
```

Comment: Should we assume that you have done all this INSIDE a `<form> ... </form>`?

Comment: Could it be `id=\".$pid.\" name=\".$name.\"` Look at your Page source, Are the `<input....` fields properly formed

Comment: sorry i'm new of php so probably I did wrong but I thought to open the form in line 7 of the code, is it correct?

Comment: Probably, I was just checking that you have actually used a `<form>` in your page as you dont show it in your snippet

Comment: please check that form is redireting confirm.php or not..

Comment: Can I ask you  how to write better ' id=\".$pid.\" name=\".$name.\" ' ?

Comment: please share all the source code so that we can review.

Comment: ok, yes, my form redirect to confirm.php, where i should do some stuff with the submission, but the page looks empty...

Comment: share the code of `confirm.php`  where it's not working. @Simone

Comment: @MuhammadSumonMollaSelim I had edited my old question adding the part with confirm.php. Thanks very much for your attention!